# How to create a Shared object(.so) file in Xcode6?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am creating an app using Swift Language in Xcode 6.1 Beta. How to create a .so file? Will the Xcode create a .so file automatically? If yes where can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

Darwin, the OS that iOS (and OS X) use, doesn't use ELF shared objects (`.so`). Instead, it uses Mach-O dynamic libraries (`.dylib`). Apple recently added support for frameworks, which includes a dynamic library inside of a directory structure, which can include headers and resources that the framework, or an app linking to the framework, might use.

Comment: To be precise, MacOSX and iOS use mach-o format libraries and object files. Shared (aka. Dynamic) libraries have the `.dylib` extension. The dynamic library(ies) packaged in a framework don't have an extension (they have the same name as the framework).

Comment: Although they do not have the `.dylib` extension, they are the same file type as `.dylib` files. In fact, some of OS X's libraries in `/usr/lib` point to a framework, such as `/usr/lib/libkrb524.dylib`, which points to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Kerberos.framework/Kerberos`.